# Query field using variable

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I am writing a stored procedure where I want to pass in the field name and data then in the procedure use the field name to reference to field to insert / update:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO trainees (txtTrainee, _field) VALUES (_txtTrainee, _data)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDAYE _field=VALUES(_field);
END
```

The parameters passed into the procedure are:

```
_txtTrainee, this is a TEXT field and contains the host name to use
_field, this is a TEXT field and contains the field name to modify
_data, this is a VARCHAR(16) and contains the data to insert or update
```

I can see I need some kind of translation function to get the contents of _field.

I'm using MariaDB 10.8

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a prepared statement:

```
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = CONCAT("INSERT INTO trainees (txtTrainee,?)",
                      "VALUES(?,?)",
                      "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?=VALUES(?)");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt USING _field,_txtTrainee,_data,_field,_field;
END
```